# Hide legend if value is 0 - Kendo UI Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, kendo-ui, pie-chart

I've have Kendo pie chart and its legend still show even there is no value.
Is it possible to hide legend that no value or value = 0. I'm passing value through the function, so I does not know which value is 0. I've tried to set up data in array but I am stuck. Anybody can help me...

Here is my script:

```
function createPieChart(a,b,c,d) {
    var e = a+b+c+d;
    var aa = a/e*100;
    var bb = b/e*100;
    var cc = c/e*100;
    var dd = d/e*100;

    var perA = Math.round(aa*100.0)/100.0;
    var perB = Math.round(bb*100.0)/100.0;
    var perC = Math.round(cc*100.0)/100.0;
    var perD = Math.round(dd*100.0)/100.0;

    var arrValue = [perA, perB, perC, perD];

    var data = [{
        "source": "Positive",
        "percentage": perA,
        "color": "#9de219",
        "explode": true
    },{
        "source": "Neutral",
        "percentage": perB,
        "color": "#90cc38"
    },{
        "source": "Negative",
        "percentage": perC,
        "color": "#068c35"
    },{
        "source": "Unknown",
        "percentage": perD,
        "color": "#006634"
    }];

    $("#chart_div").kendoChart({
        dataSource: {
          transport: {
            read: function(e) {
              e.success(data);
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
            position: "top",
            text: "Sentiment Result"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom",
            visible: true
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                visible: false,
                template: "#= category #: \n #= value#%"
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "pie",
            startAngle: 150,
            field: "percentage",
            categoryField: "source",
            colorField: "color",
            explodeField: "explode"
        }],
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            template: "${ category } - ${ value }%"
        }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind minimizing your code to where the issue exists, and elaborate more on the issue please?

Comment: I have found the way..

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
var data = [{
        "source": "Positive",
        "percentage": perA,
        "color": "#9de219",
        "explode": true
    },{
        "source": "Neutral",
        "percentage": perB,
        "color": "#90cc38"
    },{
        "source": "Negative",
        "percentage": perC,
        "color": "#068c35"
    },{
        "source": "Unknown",
        "percentage": perD,
        "color": "#006634"
    }];
```

With this code:

```
var arrValue = [perA, perB, perC, perD];
    var arrSource = ["Positive","Neutral","Negative","Unknown"];
    var arrColor = ["#9de219","#90cc38","#068c35","#006634"];
    var data=[];

    for (var i=0; i<arrValue.length; i++){
        if(arrValue[i]>0){
            data.push({
                    source: arrSource[i],
                    percentage: arrValue[i],
                    color: arrColor[i],
                    explode: true
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270719/building-the-series-of-a-kendo-chart-by-looping-through-the-json-data